# Open Window from Button without creating new windowFoo instances

Tags: c#, wpf

The problem with this is that each time you move between Windows you are creating a new object instance and adding to the memory heap (process memory, not entirely sure please correct if wrong term!). This is wasteful and poor taste in my opinion, and I'm wondering if there is another solution out there for this since I'm sure someone has thought about it before. I don't like the Pages, the navigation buttons look too much like IE in Windows 7 for a desktop application.

I have seen the solutions like this (i realize I'm not using good naming conventions, but I'm just tinkering with WPF for fun):

```
public GoogleAPI()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Closing += GoogleAPI_Closing;
}

private void GoogleAPI_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    MainWindow main = new MainWindow();
    main.Show();
}
```

This works with MainWindow creating a new GoogleAPI (my window name) instance in MainWindow in a button event.

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    GoogleAPI googleapi = new GoogleAPI();
    googleapi.Show();
    this.Hide();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

isn't it obvious to declare the `Window` instance in class level ?

```
 public class Abc()
  {
   MainWindow mw = new MainWindow();
   ///GoogleApi gp = new GoogleApi

   private void Show()
    {
     mw.Show();
     //gp.Show();
    }
```

However , the above code won't work if the window is the mainwindow , rather try this :

```
  Application.Current.MainWindow.Show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Another thing I found that is a better solution, for some forms, is to use the ShowDialog method rather than showing/hiding forms.